# How to change subclass variables after their constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a game where there are enemies which is a Enemy class which has many subclasses as variants or types of enemies, for example FastEnemy or RangedEnemy. I obviously want different enemies to have different values for health, speed and attack damage. At the moment I set these values in the subclass constructors like so:

```
public FastEnemy(Vector pos) {
    super(pos); // Enemy constructor is just setting this.pos to pos
    health = 50;
}
```

But I want to add a difficulty system where after the values are initialized, they are each multiplied by a float (the difficulty).

```
public FastEnemy(Vector pos) {
    super(pos);
    health = 50;

    applyDifficulty();
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this without post-constructor methods (which seem to be a bad practice?)

Comment: In your superclass (`Enemy`), create a method (abstract if possible) that all subclasses have to overwrite. Call that method in `Enemy`'s constructor. Set all the values there.

Comment: what f1sh is describing is the factory pattern and can solve your issue. google for that term and you'll get an abundance of further information on what to do and what not to do.